# Using immutability-helper or spread op to make changes to an object, what is better: repeatedly $set, or $merge only once an object with all changes?

Tags: javascript, normalization, shallow-copy, spread-syntax, immutability-helper

In my state I have a dictionary of a flat object:

```
export interface INodeVisibility {
  id: string;
  level: number;
  isExpanded: boolean;
}
export type NodeVisibilityDict = { [key: string]: INodeVisibility };
```

In one operation I need to iterate over a list of modifications and add or update the corresponding entries in the dictionary using [immutability-helper library](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). I wonder what would be the best approach:

1. In each iteration do a $set operation modifying or adding the dictionary entry.
2. In each iteration mutate a "modifications-object" and do a $merge of it only once at the end.

Note the data is   normalized. INodeVisibility is declared as an interface but it can be understand as a type because it is used as shown, no more properties added.

I'd vote for the second approach but I want to know what is recommended in this case.

Comment: Not sure you know this, but JS has something called the spread operator, it's maybe the reason that lib hasn't been updated for over 3 years. `in today's JavaScript this can be cumbersome:`  Yeah, when it was just `Object.assign` maybe..

Comment: I agree at least in this case I can use spread operator because a shallow copy is enought... But the question would be the same: What approach would be the best: making multiple merging inside an iteration (1), or mutate an object with the modifications in each iteration and use the spread operator only once (2)...? I'd vote for (2)

Comment: In your example your not saying what your updating, but lets assuming you just wanted to increase the level on all the records by 1, I'd do it all in one spread. eg. ->`const newNodes = nodes.map(node  => ({...node, level: node.level + 1}))`

Comment: @Keith, I have a tree of INode that will expand and contract. INodeVisibility describes if the INode is visible or not, and some data useful for displaying it. When you expand an INode for displaying all the now exposed children you will create an INodeVisibility entry for each children if not one already available. So basically I'll a list of Ids: string[] from which I'll add an INodeVisibility entry to a NodeVisibilityDictionary if not already present. That will be the case when expanding the node the first time. If the node was previously expanded it will have an entry already present.